# Maven chooses inconsistent version of indirect dependency: why, and how to prevent?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

We encountered a situation where Maven chose an inconsistent version of an indirect dependency, and I'd like to understand why, and how to prevent this in the future.

Our pom.xml file had the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but without a direct dependency on spring-core.

Both depend on spring-core: spring-web 3.1.2.RELEASE depends on spring-core 3.1.2.RELEASE (see [its pom-file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-web/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.pom)), and spring-data-jpa 1.1.0.RELEASE depends on an arbitrary 3.x version of spring-core (to be precise [3.0.7.RELEASE,4.0.0.RELEASE), see [its pom-file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.pom)).

Combining both, I would expect Maven to choose spring-core version 3.1.2.RELEASE.  However, it *does not*.  Instead, it chooses the highest from the range [3.0.7.RELEASE,4.0.0.RELEASE), which currently is 3.2.0.RELEASE.

(Reproduction scenario: put [the above pom.xml file](https://gist.github.com/4618149) (gist) in its own directory, and run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`: for me the result is [this tree](https://gist.github.com/4618160#file-maven-inconsistent-dependency-tree-txt-L29) (gist).  I get the same result for both Maven 2.2.1 on Linux and Maven 3.0.4 on Windows.)

This seems wrong, because it is *inconsistent*: a version of spring-core which spring-web's pom-file does not allow is used.

(This occurred for us when spring-core 3.2.0.RC1 became available: on the next update it was suddenly selected, and we were lucky that we got a build error because of an incompatible change between spring-core 3.1 and 3.2.  But next time we may not be so lucky, and have runtime errors which are very difficult to track down.)

**Urghh**:  I just notice that *the order of `<dependency>` declarations matters*: if I put spring-web first, then spring-core 3.1.2.RELEASE *is* selected.  What gives?

*Question:* How can we make Maven choose consistent versions of indirect dependencies, or at least warn if it makes a choice which goes against a version specified in a pom-file?

**Update**: I am asking for a general solution here.  For this specific case, I know that I can get the correct behavior by adding a dependency in `<dependencyManagement>`, specifying that I always want spring-core 3.1.2.RELEASE.  However, I would like Maven to do the Right Thing (TM) without such specific declarations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you *expect* seems logic but Maven has no chance to do this. It just resolves dependencies without the knowledge that `spring-data-jpa` might have somethig to do with `spring-core`.

The dependency resolution works as describe [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) and is the way you already described:

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a
>   version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if
>   two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree,
>   until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since
>   Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first
>   declaration wins.

So I think the only way to prevent this situation is to be aware of it and to explecitly set the version you need in your own pom.

By the way, why do you think "*This seems wrong, because it is inconsistent: a version of spring-core is used which spring-web's pom-file does not allow.*"?

A version specification of `<version>x.y</version>` is only a recommendation (see 'Note' [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges)) to use this version. If you intend to force to use this version you have to set `<version>[x.y]</version>`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that explanation!  Is there then a way to be warned --or better: break the build-- if Maven ignores a recommendation (in this case spring-web's)?

Comment: @Marnix Klooster Have a look at the goals that are provided by the [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin. There are some analyzing possibilities but I am not sure if your requirement is addressed.

Comment: In the meantime the Spring team started the [Spring IO platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) project which provides a [Spring platform bom](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven) to bundle the spring (and dependent library) versions that best fit together.

Answer (score 0):

In your dependency declaration, you can add the  part to define the indirect dependencies to not import for this dependency.

Comment: Yes, I know I can ask Maven to `<exclude>` certain dependencies, or use `<dependencyManagement>`, once I know I am in this problematic situation.  But my question is about _preventing_ this situation: if A depends on exactly version V of B, how can I prevent Maven from choosing version W, or at the very least have it warn me?  I've updated the question to try and clarity this.